# Symmetries of a regular tetrahedron

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

Let $G$ be the group of symmetries of a regular tetrahedron $T$, including orientation-reversing symmetries.

(a) Decompose the set of faces of $T$ into orbits, and describe the stabiliser of a face.

I need help with the first part of the question.

I think the stabiliser of a face corresponds to the dihedral group $D_3$

(b) Determine the order of G

It is $12$

Comment: Actually $|G|=24$, as $G=S_4$ is the group of all permutations of the vertices of the tetrahedron. There is only one orbit. You got $D_3$ right; it has 6 elements and $6\times 4=24$ (4 is the number of faces), so again $|G|=24$.

Comment: Yes, any two vertices can be interchanged by a reflection that leaves the other two unchanged.